# Pointer in border of div

Tags: css

Can someone please tell me how people get the following shape in their 
divs for menus. I'm referring to the top right corner how there's a triangle bit coming out of the rectangle...

[image]

Comment: http://www.cssarrowplease.com/

Comment: You can use the `::after` and `::before` pseudo elements to get that.

Comment: @JosephYoung Wow, just... these days.

Comment: http://ilikepixels.co.uk/drop/bubbler/

Answer (score 2):

try this,
that will help you,

https://www.sitepoint.com/pure-css3-speech-bubbles/